# Why my sidemenubarbutton is not revealing means when i tap on menu button sw_rear viewcontroller is not coming in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I have added SWRevealViewController bridge files into project from github.
And I have taken revealvc -> (sw_front)navigationcontroller -> homeVC  and revealvc -> menuvc(sw_rear)

and i also imported

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

but when i run it shows only homepg with menubarbutton and i tap menubutton the sw_rear mens tabelvc not coming

please help me in this error

and added code in homevc

```
import UIKit

class homeViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {

        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        print("button tapped")

    }
```

here added screenshot

[image: sidemenu controllers]

Comment: it is  called or not print("button tapped")

Comment: @karthik tabelvc is not showing

Comment: the method is called or not

Comment: yes method is working

Comment: can you attach the project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you added a sw_rear segue and attributed the action to what was supposed to be sw_right.

on your viewDidLoad, replace menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(*:)) with menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(*:)).